# Need to add custom security Custom HMAC Authentication for Spring Boot + Spring Rest services set-up

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have pasted RestSecurityFilter and SecurityConfig classes and when I run the below with Spring boot (without any xml classes and deployed on external Tomcat container), I get an error the below errors. I have simply taken the below samples from 2 different links and trying to make it work without any specific changes.

Query:

1) Am I duplicating anything ? Please guide
2) Can someone point me to a working example where Custom HMAC based security/authentication be configured with Spring boot & Spring Restservices ? 
3) If I dont want to use Spring Security, to keep it simple, Can I handle this as part of some authenticate() called as the first method in all my restcontroller methods ?

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.test.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint

public class RestSecurityFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    // Enable Multi-Read for PUT and POST requests
    private static final Set<String> METHOD_HAS_CONTENT = new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
        { add("PUT"); add("POST"); }
    };

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
    private Md5PasswordEncoder md5;

    public RestSecurityFilter() {
        ((RestAuthenticationEntryPoint)this.authenticationEntryPoint).setRealmName("Secure realm");
    }


    public RestSecurityFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this(authenticationManager, new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint());
        ((RestAuthenticationEntryPoint)this.authenticationEntryPoint).setRealmName("Secure realm");
    }

    public RestSecurityFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.authenticationEntryPoint = authenticationEntryPoint;
        this.md5 = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // use wrapper to read multiple times the content
        AuthenticationRequestWrapper request = new AuthenticationRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) req);
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

        // Get authorization header
        String credentials = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        // If there's not credentials return...
        if (credentials == null) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        // Authorization header is in the form <public_access_key>:<signature>
        String auth[] = credentials.split(":");

        // get md5 content and content-type if the request is POST or PUT method
        boolean hasContent = METHOD_HAS_CONTENT.contains(request.getMethod());
        String contentMd5 = hasContent ? md5.encodePassword(request.getPayload(), null) : "";
        String contentType = hasContent ? request.getContentType() : "";

        // get timestamp
        String timestamp = request.getHeader("Date");

        // calculate content to sign
        StringBuilder toSign = new StringBuilder();
        toSign.append(request.getMethod()).append("\n")
              .append(contentMd5).append("\n")
              .append(contentType).append("\n")
              .append(timestamp).append("\n")
              .append(request.getRequestURI());

        // a rest credential is composed by request data to sign and the signature
        RestCredentials restCredential = new RestCredentials(toSign.toString(), auth[1]);

        // calculate UTC time from timestamp (usually Date header is GMT but still...)
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = DateUtils.parseDate(timestamp);
        } catch (ParseException | IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Create an authentication token
        Authentication authentication = new RestToken(auth[0], restCredential, date);

        try {
            // Request the authentication manager to authenticate the token (throws exception)
            Authentication successfulAuthentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);

            // Pass the successful token to the SecurityHolder where it can be
            // retrieved by this thread at any stage.
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(successfulAuthentication);
            // Continue with the Filters
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (AuthenticationException authenticationException) {
            // If it fails clear this threads context and kick off the
            // authentication entry point process.
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            authenticationEntryPoint.commence(request, response, authenticationException);
        }
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final String LOGIN_PATH = ResourcePaths.ROOT + ResourcePaths.User.ROOT + ResourcePaths.User.LOGIN;

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private AuthSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    private AuthFailureHandler authFailureHandler;
    @Autowired
    private HttpLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
//        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
//        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
//        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new ShaPasswordEncoder());

          RestAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new RestAuthenticationProvider(); 
          return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_PATH)
                .usernameParameter(Parameters.USERNAME)
                .passwordParameter(Parameters.PASSWORD)
                .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(LOGIN_PATH, "DELETE"))
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1);

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found the solution?